# Is it possible to save a picture or put a picture in a resource folder that can be retrieve?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, image

I have this picture that I manually added to my project and added called like so.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"picture" ofType:@"png"];
```

But I am wondering if it is possible to take a picture and put it in path for resource that can be retrieve like the code above? My overal goal is to upload my picture to a server with the following code.

```
[request addFile:path forKey:@"upload"];
```

Any tips or help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can save it not in bundle but in sandbox. here is the document from apple. Documents folder is best place for it, I think. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a picture (image) to the app bundle, however you can save an image to your apps sandbox.  E.g.:

```
NSData *sourceData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
BOOL result = [sourceData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

where `image` is a `UIImage` and `savePath` is a `NSString` to the location in which you want to save the image.

If you want to save the image as JPEG (instead of PNG), use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having the `NSData` of taken picture..

```
NSData *imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image);

 [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"imagepicture.jpeg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"upload"];
```

FileName anything you can give..

If it is `PNG` image then

```
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

     [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"imagepicture.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"upload"];
```

Hope it may help you...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image first to the document directory and get back the url of image like this:

```
            NSData *thumbData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbImg);
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *imgUrl = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.png"];
            [thumbData writeToFile:imgUrl atomically:NO];
```

Now image can be getback with the imgUrl like this:

```
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imgUrl];

            Hope this helps!
```